PHP not receiving any POST request body from javascript fetch api
I am writing a program that takes input from a website and sends inputted data through phpMailer. I am sending the information in json through a post request using javascript fetch. I am also running Fat-Free with the php.The problem is that I cannot recieve the json on the server.
What I am getting in the error reporting is
500 Internal Server Error - Content-Type must be application/json
I believe it could be a cors problem but I dont know what to do and how to fix this even if it is. What I know is that the server does have a request coming in, but I cannot even get an output or anything of the post array that is coming in, as if there is no post array coming in. So I cant even see what I am dealing with. I have tried outputting the post array into a log file so I could see what I am receiving and all i get is: array( ). Even when I send test json through postMan, I get nothing in the post array. So the "Content-Type must be application/json" error could be because there is nothing in the Post array. Also, if I remove the applucation/json checker function, through postman, them email gets sent successfully the way I want it to, while if I try to send it through the site form, the email does not get sent.
JAVASCRIPT
function prepareSendList(){
    let newsletterRecipients = retrieveCheckedSubscribers();

    newsletterRecipients.forEach(recipient => {
        sendToMailer(createEnvelope(recipient));
    });
}

function createEnvelope(clientID){
    let fname = document.querySelector(`#cr-${clientID} > .fname`).textContent;
    let lname = document.querySelector(`#cr-${clientID} > .lname`).textContent;
    let email = document.querySelector(`#cr-${clientID} > .email`).textContent;
    let pm = document.querySelector(`#pm-${clientID}`).value;

    return {
        fname: fname,
        lname: lname,
        email: email,
        pm: pm
    };
}

function sendToMailer(newsletterEnvelope) {
    let uri = "http://localhost/mailer/send";
    let params = {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(newsletterEnvelope),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    };

    fetch(uri, params)
        .then(r => {
            console.log(r);
        });
}

PHP
$f3->route('GET|POST /send', function(){
    $GLOBALS['controller']->send();
});
      
function send(){
        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, var_export($_POST, true));
        fclose($myfile);

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST'){
            throw new Exception("Only POST Requests Permitted");
        }

        $content_type = isset($_POST['CONTENT_TYPE']) ? $_POST['CONTENT_TYPE'] : "";
        if(stripos($content_type, 'application/json') === false){
            throw new Exception("Content-Type must be application/json");
        }

        $body = file_get_contents("php://input");

        $envelope = json_decode($body, true);
        $GLOBALS['newsletterSender'] ->
          sendMail($envelope['email'], $envelope['fname'], $envelope['lname'],
            "ShadowGraph Newsletter", "", $envelope['pm']);
}

Updates
-Changed $_POST['Content_Type'] to apache_request_headers() and postman now passes the content-type check and so does the web form. The PostMan test sends the email, while the web form does not though. Here is the Post array dump and Apache Request Headers that are received. Do take note that the post array shows empty even for the postman test yet still sends the email how it is supposed to.
Log from Postman Request
POST: array (
)
Apache Req Headers: array (
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'User-Agent' => 'PostmanRuntime/7.40.0',
  'Accept' => '*/*',
  'Postman-Token' => '23c9485f-17aa-48d1-b546-a0aa77877120',
  'Host' => 'localhost',
  'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Length' => '134',
)

Log from Web Form Request
POST: array (
)
Apache Req Headers: array (
  'Host' => 'localhost',
  'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
  'Content-Length' => '79',
  'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
  'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
  'sec-ch-ua' => '"Not/A)Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="126", "Google Chrome";v="126"',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform' => '"Windows"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile' => '?0',
  'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Accept' => '*/*',
  'Origin' => 'http://localhost',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site' => 'same-origin',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode' => 'cors',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest' => 'empty',
  'Referer' => 'http://localhost/mailer/mailer',
  'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
  'Accept-Language' => 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8',
)

And here is the way I am collecting this information
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($myfile, 'POST: ' . var_export($_POST, true) . "\n");
        fwrite($myfile, 'Apache Req Headers: ' . var_export(apache_request_headers(), true) . "\n");
        fclose($myfile);

FIXED
-The problem was That I was querying the textarea correctly for the pm.

Have you set any headers through the $f3->CORS variable? I didn't see any examples in your code. Look at CORS on here. https://fatfreeframework.com/3.8/quick-reference

You're looking in the wrong place for the content type. It's an HTTP header, not a request parameter, so instead of looking in $_POST['CONTENT_TYPE'], look in $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'].
You can also use the apache_request_headers() function to fetch all the incoming request headers (and no, you don't need to be using Apache for this to work):
var_dump(apache_request_headers());


So this goes through and the content type headers are as supposed to be, application/json. Postman and web form passes the content type check now. The web form still does not send the email though
